# Moment Timezone without historic data

Tags: momentjs

As far as I can tell Moment Timezone features historic timezone data as well. What if historic data is not required? If only the very recent and future dates will be used, would there be a way to strip this historic data so the amount of data will be smaller?

Comment: When reading "historic timezone data" i would assume it means it is aware of DST changes, which is a very useful feature when you want to know something about an event that took place just before that change. I would not assume this is a feature that costs you (a lot of) extra storage of data, if _any_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it could be done - however, there is nothing to *automatically* do this.  You would have to manipulate the data yourself.  If you ever need to update the data, you'll have to do it all over again.

For example, consider the full zone data for a single time zone:

```
{
    "zones": {
        "America/Chicago": [
            "-5:50:36 - LMT 1883_10_18_12_9_24 -5:50:36",
            "-6 US C%sT 1920 -6",
            "-6 Chicago C%sT 1936_2_1_2 -6",
            "-5 - EST 1936_10_15_2 -5",
            "-6 Chicago C%sT 1942 -6",
            "-6 US C%sT 1946 -6",
            "-6 Chicago C%sT 1967 -6",
            "-6 US C%sT"
        ]
    },
    "rules": {
        "US": [
            "1918 1919 2 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1918 1919 9 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "1942 1942 1 9 7 2 0 1 W",
            "1945 1945 7 14 7 23 1 1 P",
            "1945 1945 8 30 7 2 0 0 S",
            "1967 2006 9 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "1967 1973 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1974 1974 0 6 7 2 0 1 D",
            "1975 1975 1 23 7 2 0 1 D",
            "1976 1986 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1987 2006 3 1 0 2 0 1 D",
            "2007 9999 2 8 0 2 0 1 D",
            "2007 9999 10 1 0 2 0 0 S"
        ],
        "Chicago": [
            "1920 1920 5 13 7 2 0 1 D",
            "1920 1921 9 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "1921 1921 2 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1922 1966 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1922 1954 8 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "1955 1966 9 0 8 2 0 0 S"
        ]
    }
}
```

If you only cared about the *current* rule, that could reduce down to this:

```
{
    "zones": {
        "America/Chicago": [
            "-6 US C%sT"
        ]
    },
    "rules": {
        "US": [
            "2007 9999 2 8 0 2 0 1 D",
            "2007 9999 10 1 0 2 0 0 S"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for stripping historic data: 

$.each(tz.rules, function(key, items){
  $.each(items.slice(0,items.length-1), function(index, item){
    new_items = [];
    if(item.substring(0,9) == items[items.length-1].substring(0,9)) {
      new_items.push(item);
    }
    new_items.push(items[items.length-1]);
  })
  tz.rules[key] = new_items;
})
$.each(tz.zones, function(key, items){
  tz.zones[key] = [items[items.length-1]];
})

Answer (score 1):

I took celalo's comment from Matt Johnson's comment and ran it on the current timezone data and posted it to a github gist. You can download it here: https://gist.github.com/vongillern/9622709.

For reference, it is about 33kb instead of 177kb for original with all the history.